# Google Apps Script - Want to truncate a text in a particular column in a form sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to truncate an automatic text (a8a2dc4e-ba77-450d-8352-0044365e7322) from a particular column in a sheet to the first four of the text(a8a2) using the left function.... i was unable to do it, i was getting error messages, i couldn't use the function on the sheet itself cos, the sheet clear all function per day

this is script below

```
function Truncate () {
  
// Get Spreadsheet and sheets
  var R = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet Link");
    var Choices = R.getSheetByName("Choices");
  
     UniqueNo = Choices.getRange("H2:H").left(H:4"); //sheet column range and the left function
    }
```

please What wrong with my script and which script can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issues:

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#:%7E:text=Google%20Apps%20Script%20is%20a,Calendar%2C%20Drive%2C%20and%20more.) uses JavaScript and **not** google formulas. You
  can't just use **formulas** but you can take advantage of everything
  that is supported in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

---

### Explanation:

- Your goal is to get the values of column H, apply an operation to every element to get the first 4 digits of each element in this array and then paste/overwrite the values back to column H.
- To achieve that you must use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to get the values of column H. Firstly, you use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get the values in a 1D array. Then you need to apply a function to every element of this array to get the first 4 digits of every cell. Use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do that.
- One way to get the first 4 digits of a string is to use [substring(0,4)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

---

### Solution:

```
function truncate() {
    const R        = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetId");
    const Choices  = R.getSheetByName("Choices");
    const Hrange = Choices.getRange("H2:H");
    const data    = Hrange.getValues().flat().map(r => [r.toString().substring(0,4)] );
    Hrange.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: how can i use this on multiple sheets

Comment: @KasimUsman I would like to invite you to post this in a different question since stackoverflow does not allow follow-up questions. Sorry for the inconvenience.